# Recursion in Python (factorial function)

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

I hope this is not too much of a stupid question, but why does the 'return 1' statement in this Python code return the factorial of a number? This also happens for 'return True', which I understand is equivalent to 'return 1'

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Comment: `return 1` does not return the factorial of a number all by itself; it depends on all the other values that have already been calculated in the recursion chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n == 0` is the base case of the recursive function. Factorial of 0 is 1: [reference](https://www.thoughtco.com/why-does-zero-factorial-equal-one-3126598)

Once the base case returns 1, the statement `return n * factorial(n-1)` will have the form: `return n * 1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

in python when you multiply a number by True it will operate like you are multiply by One,
and when you multiply a number by False it will operate like when you multiply by Zero.

so this is why you get a factorial af a number even if you use:

```
return True
```

instead of

```
return 1
```

but if you will call factorial(0) you will get True instead of 1.